# oracle pl/sql issue on procedure way of execution

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a scenario I have a table `t1` which has two table names they are `san` and `man`. And now the two tables `san`, `man` each table has multiple table filenames like table `san` has two file names (`audi.txt` ,`mercedes.txt`) and the second table `man` has one file name (`hundai.txt`). I wrote a procedure where it can return number of rows in the which are present in the respective table with the respective file name. Here is the procedure:

:sql queries

```
-- for creating t1 table--

CREATE TABLE HR.T1
(
  NAMES       VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  MAPPING_ID  VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
);

SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into HR.T1
   (NAMES, MAPPING_ID)
 Values
   ('san', '1');
Insert into HR.T1
   (NAMES, MAPPING_ID)
 Values
   ('man', '1');
COMMIT;

-----------sql query for 'san' table----

CREATE TABLE HR.SAN
(
  SRC_FILENAME  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
);

SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into HR.SAN
   (SRC_FILENAME)
 Values
   ('audi.txt');
Insert into HR.SAN
   (SRC_FILENAME)
 Values
   ('mercedes.txt');
COMMIT;

------sql query for man table ----

CREATE TABLE HR.MAN
(
  SRC_FILENAME  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
);

SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into HR.MAN
   (SRC_FILENAME)
 Values
   ('hundai.txt');
COMMIT;

-------package spec -----

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE HR.file_entry

AS

PROCEDURE PKG_PROC_FILES(L_MAPPING_ID NUMBER); 
procedure insert_proc (l_object_name VARCHAR2);
END;

-----package body -----


    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY HR.file_entry
AS

   PROCEDURE PKG_PROC_FILES (L_MAPPING_ID NUMBER)

AS
      V_TABLE_NAME    VARCHAR2 (50);
  V_SCHEMA_NAME   VARCHAR2 (50);

  TYPE CURTYPE IS REF CURSOR;

  V_SCHEMA_NAME   VARCHAR2 (50);


     ----
      CURSOR TARGET_OBJ_CUR
      IS
         SELECT DISTINCT names
           FROM t1
          WHERE MAPPING_ID = L_MAPPING_ID;
   BEGIN

    FOR I IN TARGET_OBJ_CUR
      LOOP
         INSERT_PROC (I.names);
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('TARGET_TABLE_NAME= ' || I.names);
      END LOOP;
   END;



PROCEDURE INSERT_PROC (L_OBJECT_NAME VARCHAR2)

   AS

      V_TABLE_NAME       VARCHAR2 (50);
      V_SCHEMA_NAME      VARCHAR2 (50);
      V_QUERY            VARCHAR2 (50);

      TYPE CURTYPE IS REF CURSOR;

      V_SRC_FILE_NAMES   VARCHAR2 (200);
      CUR                CURTYPE;

BEGIN

      V_QUERY := 'select distinct src_filename from ' || L_OBJECT_NAME;
      OPEN CUR FOR V_QUERY;

      LOOP
         FETCH CUR INTO V_SRC_FILE_NAMES;

         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('SOURCE FILE NAMES 1 = ' || V_SRC_FILE_NAMES);
         COMMIT;

         EXIT WHEN CUR%NOTFOUND;
      END LOOP;

      CLOSE CUR;

   END;

END;
/
```

After executing the procedure I have multiple names from DB:

```
O/P
SOURCE FILE NAMES = mercedes.txt
SOURCE FILE NAMES = audi.txt
SOURCE FILE NAMES = audi.txt
TARGET_TABLE_NAME= san
SOURCE FILE NAMES = hundai.txt
SOURCE FILE NAMES = hundai.txt
TARGET_TABLE_NAME= man
```

In the below O/P I need to get only distinct source file names from table butI am unable to understand why am I getting the `audi.txt` and `hundai.txt` multiple times. Can anyone help me out to solve this issue? I need a file name once to be printed in the output like `mercedes.txt` which has been printed only once in the output.

Answer (score 1):

`EXIT WHEN CUR%NOTFOUND;` exit statement needs to be checked after `fetch` in the `INSERT_PROC` procedure, not before `end loop` . And why you use `commit` after `dbms_output.put_line` ?